# Rejecting message based on email header ( in Office365 )

Tags: office365, exchange-server

I have a very simple 'mail flow' rule which states that exchange should reject a message when it sees an email that has a header set to a specific value. The rule is in active/enforced mode but I can't get it to work.

My guess is that exchange is unable to find or match the header (Although the test email I am sending has header set to correct value).

I have tried that same (rejection) rule for the 'subject' field and it worked as expected. I am using custom/non-standard header named "Action" but its a valid mail/mime header.

Attached is the screenshot of the rule.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How does your header look like in the message? Maybe there's no colon (:) symbol in the header?

I have a transport rule that works like a charm.

Header example: `X-Spam: yes`

And the transport rule looks the same as yours: 
[transport rule pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s2M5.png)

Comment: Header looks like this `Action: block` . I verified mail client is setting this header properly but it seems its being stripped from the email ( by exchange ) at some point. Possibly before rule matching. Does your email retaining the X-Spam header when it gets to the destination ?

Comment: I have mail gateway postfix servers who add header to incomming messages. Works without trouble. 

But you say that your mail client adds that header? As far as I notices, microsoft outlooks often deletes some headers when forward messages as an attachment.

Comment: Can you provide your mail flow scheme? You have some service that sends mail and then message flows out using exchange transport and then header disappers?

Comment: I have javamail client that sends out email with Action header set, to exchange (smtp.office365.com) , the reject rule which should look for the header and should reject the email if the header is set, but it doesnt. Similar rule works for Message-ID header ( which is a standard mail header).

Comment: Don't have any ideas for now.
Maybe you can try to rename your header and try again?

Comment: Ok, switching MTA host from smtp.office365.com to smtp.gmail.com works, I can see my header intact and my rule triggers. This confirms why your rule was working, you are probably using an MTA which is not smtp.office365.com. This still does not solve my problem but atleast now I know what the problem is. Probably should tell Microsoft support about this behavior. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, looks like office365 rewrites your header. I'm glad you solved it. If you don't use a cloud solution for sending mail, you can deploy local postfix or any other relay that will forward messages to office365 (you can add your IP as trusted).
You're welcome!